# How to highlight current line of execution in debug perspective in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to see the current execution line highlighted in green with arrow at the left in my Eclipse Debug perspective.

Unfortunately I don't know how to set it. I have seen it in some Eclipse platform and wondering if I can set it to display.

I am using Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2.

Comment: Do you want to see the current execution line while the code is executing? As far as I know, Eclipse only highlights execution lines when a thread is paused.

Comment: I added a breakpoint and then debug but the current execution line is not highlighted.

Comment: Sounds like the breakpoint line isn't being executed. You confirm this by adding `System.out.println("Executing bp line")` just before the breakpoint line. (This may generate too much output if the line is executed many times; in that case, set a flag the first time through and skip the output once the flag is set.)

Comment: The line is most definitely executed. I went through the execution fully. The only issue is that the line of execution is not highlighted and the arrow is not seen to the left of the window.

Comment: Does the thread halt at the breakpoint? If not, check that the debugger is attached to the process. Do you see the process thread(s) in the debugger perspective?

Comment: Yes I do. The thread halts at bp.

Answer (score 13):

In debug perspective, double click to the left of a line to set a break point. Once a break point is set, you can highlight running code line by line.

If it doesn't work as expected, just check your preferences here:
*Window > Preferences > General > Editors > All Text Editors > Annotations > Debug Call Stack and Debug Current Instruction Pointer*

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, after I put a breakpoint, the execution proceeds line by line though the line is not highlighted.

Comment: check settings in preferences

Comment: I Dont know which settings in preferences correspond to this. I tried several. They didnt work.

Comment: Tried your update too. No luck. Changing them doesnt have any effect.

Comment: This answers the question, barring any strange problem the OP had going on.

Comment: @Viidhya You need to add the project to debugger source.
DebugConfigurations > Source tab > Add... > Java Project > Select All (or select your project) > Ok > Ok > Apply 
Relaunch debugger..that's all

Answer (score 6):

I just had to reboot eclipse, and everything started working perfectly.

Comment: @Akhileshkrishnan: Not sure what a "definite answer" is; it worked for me right now.

Comment: I am using Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) Build id: 20180405-1200 and restarting Eclipse fixed this issue for me as well. No clue why it stopped following the debugging line and highlighting, but glad a simple restart fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Check your class path and be sure the project source directory is in there. If you are debugging an enterprise application clean temp and working directories and republish your application.

Answer (score 0):

For others, if it can solve yours. I had similar issue. I see it highlighted, stopped at breakpoint. But I wasn't able to use step by step (F6) debug. Reason was that eclipse stopped due to break point and highlighted/selected top thread in debug.

So I selected current thread, by verifying one by one, till the current code(stopped due to breakpoint) highlighted.

To see threads running add debug view if not shown. Window > Show view > Debug.

This also helped me while debugging 2 threads separately on running programme.

There seems no short keys to locate current Thread from code stopped due to breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I hadn't terminated the debugger. Clicking the red square terminate button (shown in the screenshot below) and then running the debug again made the current line show up highlighted again.

[image: screenshot showing the terminate button]

Answer (score 0):

I get this from time to time and haven't been able to pin down the root cause but usually it resolves itself if I terminate the debugger, close the source code window with the breakpoint and then restart the debugger. When the breakpoint is hit Eclipse is forced to re-open the source window and then the breakpoint line is highlighted and Eclipse appears to highlight lines going forward.

Answer (score -1):

DebugConfigurations > Source tab > Add... > Java Project > Select All (or select your project) > Ok > Ok > Apply Relaunch debugger

i just repost what Sudhanshu has writen, it worked very well for  me.