# my debugging cursor is not visible in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I changed a few properties around in eclipse and now when I debug my project, my debugging cursor (the arrow) does not appear any more. I can still use the Debug view to see exactly where my debugger is based on the line number, however the arrow and the highlight that eclipse does on the line is not showing. Is there a way I can make this visible?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you running?  And what sort of settings have you tried so far?  Have you tried googling for the answer?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537803/how-to-highlight-current-line-of-execution-in-debug-perspective-in-eclipse?rq=1

Comment: @Welshboy I'm using Eclipse EE Luna Service Release 4.4.3. The settings I've changed were to edit the Step Filters on in the Debug view. thanks

Comment: Restore to defaults. Eclipse has this. Use it in the preference window you broke

Comment: Have you tried turning Eclipse off and on again?

Comment: @Kon I tried to restore to defaults with no luck